# Apache running on which Port

Tags: python, apache, python-2.7, mod-wsgi, httpd.conf

Is there a way to programatically find out which PORT Apache is running on from within a Python program (WEB Application using mod_wsgi)

I can always do a grep on httpd.conf but wanted to know if there is some other standard programatic way of achieving this.

Comment: Is there a non-academic reason why you need to know this?

Comment: Yes. I am implementing a WSDL WEB Service using Apache. In the service definition I am required to indicate the IP and the PORT. The non-academic reason being that I don't want to hard code the PORT :-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Environment variable SERVER_PORT should give it to you:

```
def application(env, start_response):
    start_response('200 OK', [('Content-Type', 'text/html')])
    return [ env['SERVER_PORT'] ]
```